# In JAGS, how can I fix a parameter to a distribution, as opposed to just a constant?

Tags: r, bayesian, prior, jags, stan

The first code chunk below (model1) is a JAGS script designed to estimate a two-group Gaussian mixture model with unequal variances. I am looking for a way to fix one of the parameters (say $\mu_2$) to a particular distribution (e.g., dnorm(0,0.0001)). I know how to fix $\mu_2$ to a constant (e.g., see model2 in code chunk 2), though I cannot find a way to fix $\mu_2$ to my prior belief(e.g., see model3 in code chunk 3, which shows conceptually what I am trying to do).

Thanks in advance!

**Code chunk 1**

```
model1 = "
model {

for (i in 1:n1){
y1[i] ~ dnorm (mu1 , phi1) 
}

for (i in 1:n2){ 
y2[i] ~ dnorm (mu2 , phi2) 
}

# Priors
phi1 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
phi2 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
sigma2.1 <- 1/phi1
sigma2.2 <- 1/phi2
mu1 ~ dnorm (0,0.0001) 
mu2 ~ dnorm (0,0.0001)

# Create a variable for the mean difference

delta <- mu1 - mu2

}
"
```

**Code chunk 2**

```
model2 = "
model {

for (i in 1:n1){
y1[i] ~ dnorm (mu1 , phi1) 
}

for (i in 1:n2){ 
y2[i] ~ dnorm (mu2 , phi2) 
}

# Priors
phi1 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
phi2 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
sigma2.1 <- 1/phi1
sigma2.2 <- 1/phi2
mu1 ~ dnorm (0,0.0001) 
mu2 <- 1.27

# Create a variable for the mean difference

delta <- mu1 - mu2

}
"
```

**Code chunk 3**

````
model3 = "
model {

for (i in 1:n1){
y1[i] ~ dnorm (mu1 , phi1) 
}

for (i in 1:n2){ 
y2[i] ~ dnorm (mu2 , phi2) 
}

# Priors
phi1 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
phi2 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
sigma2.1 <- 1/phi1
sigma2.2 <- 1/phi2
mu1 ~ dnorm (0,0.0001) 
mu2 <- dnorm (0,0.0001) 

# Create a variable for the mean difference

delta <- mu1 - mu2

}
"
```
````

Comment: Why not use the distributional operator instead of the assignment operator in model 3. That is, why not use `mu2 ~ dnorm(...)` instead of `mu2 <- dnorm(...)`?

Comment: Because that would tell JAGS I wanted to freely estimate mu2. I want to fix mu2.

Comment: `mu2 <- dnorm(0,0.0001)` makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to express my prior belief of `mu2`:

1. I believe very strongly that `mu2` can only be a single value, 1.27 say, in which case I can use the assignment operator as shown in **chunk2**.
2. I believe that `mu2` is most probably some value, 0 say, but with ~95% probability I think it could be between -0.0002 and 0.0002. In that case I can specify a prior distribution on `mu2` as is shown in **chunk1**.

I think **2.** is the answer to the title of the OP.